How do I Transfer Keyframe Animation to Different Model?

When I copied and paste the key frames to another model the rotation of the bones don’t match up. Any idea on how to fix this?

Hello, probably because the bones don't have the same orientation, you need to check in Edit mode, you can share your file here: https://blend-exchange.com/

I’ll check it out in edit mode.

The two rigs need to have the same bone names, hierarchy, orientations, and as close as a similar rest pose and proportions, otherwise the pasted animation will either not find the bone to paste to, or will give a wildly different result.
Hierarchy and proportions
If your rigs are not using the same hierarchy or roughly similar proportions, that's usually because either the models are too different and there's not much you can do, or the rigs are not made the same to begin with. Either copy one rig from one character to the other, or accept that you will have big differences to fix later with layered animation anytime you copy animations across rigs.
Rest pose
Since the animation is calculated as a difference from the rest pose, wildly different rest pose across characters will give wildly different results when you transfer animations from one to the other. You could fix that using layered animation, or if you can, make sure you have as close of a rest pose across characters.
To change a rest pose, you can either do it in edit mode, or make a new pose in Pose Mode and then use ⎈ CtrlA to apply the pose as a rest pose. Be aware that a rest pose is a definitive change. If you have other animations already made, they will be affected by the change of rest pose.
Bone names and orientations
To check the bone names and orientations, you can turn on the armature's viewport display options "names" and "axes":

Wrong names are easy to fix. You have a bulk rename operator you can call by hitting ⎈ CtrlF2, don't forget to set it to "bones":

To fix bones orientations, go in Edit mode, select some bones and hit ⇧ ShiftN and select the orientation to which orient the selected bones' local Z towards.
It is common practice to use the X axis as the folding axis. As you can see in the rigify rig in the above screenshots.
For any changes that are symmetrical, you can beforehand enable X mirroring in the viewport tools options so that any changes made in one side are mirrored to the other:

